# Trying to react to a message by message ID in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've recently been delving into coding so I apologise if the question sounds stupid (I have tried to search for answers), but I can't seem to make the bot react to a specific message on demand.

Here's the code:

```
    if (msg.content === 'rrredo') {
        const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'roles');
        channel.messages.fetch(813776066266005554).then(rrmsg => {
        rrmsg.react('<:soundcloud:803698500877156413>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:github:803698500860248064>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:googlehangouts:803698500557865001>')      
        rrmsg.react('<:reddit:803697537067253791>')        
        rrmsg.react('<:signal:803697536694222908> ') 
        rrmsg.react('<:youtube:803697536690421821> ')
        rrmsg.react('<:WhatsApp:803697536677969950>')  
        rrmsg.react('<:Twitter:803697536488439819>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Skype:803697536451084289> ') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Instagram:803697536338362369>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Snapchat:803697536278855774>') 
    }); 
    };
  });
```

The bot is intended to, when receiving a message called 'ping', react to a message with message ID 813776066266005554.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: grammar

Comment: ID's must be strings, not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord accepts IDs as strings not integers. True code:

```
if (msg.content === 'rrredo') {
        const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'roles');
        channel.messages.fetch("813776066266005554").then(rrmsg => {
        rrmsg.react('<:soundcloud:803698500877156413>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:github:803698500860248064>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:googlehangouts:803698500557865001>')      
        rrmsg.react('<:reddit:803697537067253791>')        
        rrmsg.react('<:signal:803697536694222908> ') 
        rrmsg.react('<:youtube:803697536690421821> ')
        rrmsg.react('<:WhatsApp:803697536677969950>')  
        rrmsg.react('<:Twitter:803697536488439819>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Skype:803697536451084289> ') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Instagram:803697536338362369>') 
        rrmsg.react('<:Snapchat:803697536278855774>') 
    }); 
    };
  });
```